# Read local storage when iOS app enters background

Tags: ios, uiwebview, local-storage

Objective-c is extremely new to me:

The method below triggers when my iphone app moves to the background.  In that moment I want to grab the items in UIWebView's local storage and store in the app.

I'm getting the error `"No known class for selector 'stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString'"`.  How do I inject this dependency into this function while still keeping `UIApplication`?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    //Persist local storage data
    NSLog(@"Persisting local storage since app entering background");

    //Reading local storage item
    NSString *jsString = @"localStorage.getItem('mpo.subdomain');";
    NSString *someKeyValue = [UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

    // Store your subdomain in iPhone persistence variable and use it later in the application
    NSUserDefaults *userdefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userdefault setObject:someKeyValue forKey:@"subdomain"];
    [userdefault synchronize];

    //use of User default
    NSLog(@"User Subdomain %@",[userdefault valueForKey:@"subdomain"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]` is attempting to invoke a CLASS method called `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` on the UIWebview class. The `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method is an instance method. You need to send that message to an instance of UIWebView, not the class.

If you have a property myWebView then you'd use the code:

```
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]
```

That sends the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` message to the **instance** of UIWebview pointed to by the `self.myWebView` property. That's what you want.

Comment: BTW, why are you learning Objective-C? As a new iOS developer I would suggest learning Swift (Specifically Swift 3.) That is the direction Apple is heading for all new development. Objective-C is on the way out. In another 5 years the only Objective-C code is likely to be legacy code.

Comment: Thanks Duncan!  I'll double-check to test this today.  To answer your question, I'm working in objective-c because I'm modifying an existing project.  I'll check and see if I can mix swift syntax inside the project.. not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Duncan, any chance you can help with next steps here?  :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943693/stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-does-nothing

Comment: It is quite possible. Swift and Objective-C play together nicely.